# Is it correct to say “Have an inconvenience”

Tags: grammaticality

I am wondering about what structure i need to use when I want to express an inconvenience that i experienced. 
Is it correct to say,
 : I have / feel an inconvenience to bring my toothbrush.
 : I have/ feel an inconvenience to bring my toothbrush.
 : I have an inconvenience bringing my toothbrush.
 : I have an inconvenience that i bring my toothbrush.

Instead of saying “it is inconvenient for me to bring my brush”

Answer (score 1):

You are not using "inconvenience" with the usual correct meaning. It means the general quality, and not a specific feeling, object or action. This means that "I have inconvenience..." is not idiomatic.

It may be possible to use a very long sentence like

> If I brought my toothbrush I would experience inconvenience.

But this is not a normal sentence. But you already know the right answer: the adjective is how this is expressed:

> It's inconvenient for me to bring my brush.